# Change text from db client side

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

I got this value from a MySQL DB field: "september 9 @ 08:00 - 17:00".
Can i change this **client side** to **9 september**? I tried with JavaScript but i didn't come even close.

The date may change.

Desired result in browser: **9 september**

Thank you,

Comment: `I tried with JavaScript` can we see what you tried?

Comment: Are you sure to get the format from mysqldb `"september 9 @ 08:00 - 17:00"`

Comment: @fvu
I will upload this evening when home. don't expect to much :)

Comment: @prasad
yes, its a varchar field.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty uncommon output for a datetime value from the database. One solution is to simply strip all text after the `@` character - if you're sure the output format stays as is:

```js
var datetime = 'september 9 @ 19:20 - 20:00';
var result = datetime.substr(0, datetime.indexOf('@')).trim();

console.log(result); // outputs 'september 9'

var date = new Date(result);
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

console.log(date.getDate(), months[date.getMonth()]); // outputs '9 September'
```

Comment: Hi Jason K,

Thank you for the respond. Yes, it is a string in a nvarchar field.
But it's: september 9 @ 08:00 - 17:00

How can i switch the day and month with your code?

Comment: Hi thx,  but that was not wat i was looking for. the value of the field can chacnge, you don't have to see it as a date.  i simply want to swat the first two words.

Comment: The second output is `NaN undefined` in Safari. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

The values you want are in the string, so just reformat it:

```js
var s = 'September 9 @ 08:00 - 17:00';
var b = s.split(' ');
console.log(b[1] + ' ' + b[0]);

// You could even do
console.log(s.replace(/(\w+) (\d+)(.*)/, '$2 $1'));

// Or if you want to just swap the month and day and keep the rest
console.log(s.replace(/(\w+) (\d+)/, '$2 $1'));
```